# Run same repetitive job in parallel in Gitlab CICD

Tags: gitlab-ci

is there a better way of running multiple jobs in parallel without repetition.

I need to run multiple python scripts simultaneously with different variables such as:

```
python main.py --table table_1
python main.py --table table_2
python main.py --table table_3
```

`gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
extract-table1:
  stage:
   - run
  extends:
    - .execute-script
  script:
    - python main.py --table table_1

extract-table2:
  stage:
   - run
  extends:
    - .execute-script
  script:
    - python main.py --table table_2
...
and so on..
```

How do avoid repetition like this? But I don't want to loop them because I need them in parallel. I have 10 tables to do. So repetition seems too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [parallel:matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) look like:

```yaml
extract-table:
  stage:
   - run
  extends:
    - .execute-script
  script:
    - python main.py --table "$TABLE_NAME" --class "$CLASS_NAME"
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - TABLE_NAME: [table_1, table_2, table_3]
        CLASS_NAME: class_1
      - TABLE_NAME: [table_4, table_5, table_6]
        CLASS_NAME: class_2
      - TABLE_NAME: [table_7, table_8]
        CLASS_NAME: [class_3, class_4]
```

job will run

```
python main.py --table "table_1" --class "class_1"
python main.py --table "table_2" --class "class_1"
python main.py --table "table_3" --class "class_1"
```

```
python main.py --table "table_4" --class "class_2"
python main.py --table "table_5" --class "class_2"
python main.py --table "table_6" --class "class_2"
```

```
python main.py --table "table_7" --class "class_3"
python main.py --table "table_8" --class "class_3"
python main.py --table "table_7" --class "class_4"
python main.py --table "table_8" --class "class_4"
```

Comment: What if the script takes >1 arguments? eg `- python main.py --table "$TABLE_NAME" --class "$CLASS"`

Comment: I update my sample. you can use multiple dimensional matrices.

Comment: Can you add "This answer is useful"?